# PCA before Affinity Propagation (AP)

Tags: python, clustering, k-means, pca

I have a large-ish dataset (100k samples, ~100 features), that I am trying to cluster, to an unknown number of clusters.
I thought of using PCA first, to reduce dimensionality, since I understand that distances (euclidean, cosine) in high-dimensionality might not be actually accurate.

However, I found very little on using PCA before AP, unlike K-Means, which made me wonder - is there any reason to not use PCA and then affinity propagation?

Answer (score 2):

Independent of the number of features, you will obviously need much more than

3 * 100.000 * 100.000 * 8 bytes

of ram (with double precision floats). That is 240.000.000.000 or about   240 GB. Not only is this a lot of RAM to have, but AP will have to do *many* passes over this RAM, so this will take forever, even *after* computing the distance matrix.

So clearly PCA won't help. You just cannot afford an algorithm with O(n²) memory and O(n²) runtime. PCA reduces d, but the runtime of AP itself does not depend on d.

Comment: Got it. So does this mean that AP can be used only on significantly smaller data sets (assuming no ultra RAM available)?

Comment: Just do an experiment yourself. Generate simple data with n=1000, n=2000, n=4000, n=8000 and then estimate the cost.